# Angular 4 prod build error after installing new angular cli version

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-chips

**I am getting following angular cli error when trying to build with prod flag.**

previously i used angular-cli **1.6.3** then its working perfectly,but now i have newly install angular-cli **1.7.0** in different PC and gives following error when doing ng build --prod

> in ./src/$$_gendir/node_modules/ngx-chips/ngx-chips.ngfactory.ts
>   "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-chips/components/index'
>   in 'D:\Project\angular-test\src\$$_gendir\node_modules\ngx-chips

do i need to downgrade my angular-cli version to 1.6.3 or upgrade my project cli version to 1.7.0?
here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-sample-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "async": "^2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.5.11",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.10.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/papaparse": "^4.1.28",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```